# How can I check the time of compiling?

Tags: c++

I got a competition from programming and in problems,there is a timelimit(0.1seconds).So,I need to check if my program works well before I upload it(if it does not compile more than 0.1 seconds).
How can I check it?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Some command-line compilers list the time it took to compile a program.

Comment: "Works well" means what? 0.1 seconds on what hardware? This is way too vague to even start to answer.

Comment: Wait, the *compile* time has to be 0.1 seconds, or the *execution* time?

Comment: On Unix/Linux you could put `time` on your compile command line, e.g. `time g++ hello.cpp`.

Comment: it'd be wise to tell us more about your project so people may help you better, have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Compilation time on a remote machine is nothing you can determine on your local machine (unless both machines are identical with respect respect to soft- and hardware and things they are concurrently executing, events interrupting the compiler etc), so there's nothing you can do to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

On debian linux you can run `time g++ your_program.cpp -o outputName` and it will output the real, user, and system time

Answer (score 0):

The dev-C++ compiler always says the time it takes to run when the program finishes running. Borland also does but I wouldn't recomend using that because it's a lot of working in the command line with that compiler. If you're using code that requires user input that would delay the time that the program takes to run due to human response time.